# PHP upload not working, no error

Tags: php, upload

I have a site where a user can upload an image (which worked perfectly a few days ago and I didn't even change anything related to the upload)

The file ownership is set to www-data and I also tried with permission 777, so that shouldn't be the reason it's not working.

enctype/data etc are also set

This is the code:

```
switch ($_FILES['upload']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                $msg="There is no error, the file uploaded with success.";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $msg="The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $msg="The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $msg="The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $msg="No file was uploaded.";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $msg="Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $msg="Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.";
                break;
           default:
               $msg="unknown error with upload";
       }
       echo("<script>console.log('".$msg."'); </script>");


        //process image
        if($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']!=null){
            $imgPath="../assets/img/horses/horse".$id.".jpg";
            if((bool)getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])){
                $writeimage = fopen($imgPath, "w");
                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $imgPath)){
                    echo("<script>console.log('couldn't move img');</script>");
                } else{
                    echo("<script>console.log('image uploaded');</script>");
                }
                fclose($writeimage);
            } else{
                echo("  <div class='alert alert-warning' id='notSaved' style='margin-top:20px;'>
                            Fehler: Die Datei die hochgeladen werden soll, scheint kein Bild zu sein.
                        </div>");
            }
        }
```

The output is 

"There is no error, the file uploaded with success.

image uploaded."

but the file doesn't change/appear on the server.

Also I can probably delete the lines $writeimage = fopen($imgPath, "w"); and fclose($writeImage), can't I?

Comment: You've got your logic turned around: `move_uploaded_file()` returns `true` on success.

Comment: as per your if condition you are facing an error tha't why it is giving message image uploaded just changed those messages and debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I can see some issue.

```
//process image
if($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']!=null){
    $image="../assets/img/horses/horse".$id.".jpg";
    if((bool)getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])){
        $writeimage = fopen($imgPath, "w");
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $imgPath)){
            echo("<script>console.log('couldn't move img');</script>");
        } else{
            echo("<script>console.log('image uploaded');</script>");
        }
        fclose($writeimage);
    } else{
        echo("  <div class='alert alert-warning' id='notSaved' style='margin-top:20px;'>
                    Fehler: Die Datei die hochgeladen werden soll, scheint kein Bild zu sein.
                </div>");
    }
}
```

Please check where is  $imgPath variable is defined? it should be $image.
No need to use fopen and fclose

So Your cose shouled be...

```
if($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']!=null){
    $image="../assets/img/horses/horse".$id.".jpg";
    if((bool)getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $image)){
            echo("<script>console.log('couldn't move img');</script>");
        } else{
            echo("<script>console.log('image uploaded');</script>");
        }
    } else{
        echo("  <div class='alert alert-warning' id='notSaved' style='margin-top:20px;'>
                    Fehler: Die Datei die hochgeladen werden soll, scheint kein Bild zu sein.
                </div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah the $imgPath typo was the problem, must have changed it accidentally^^

Comment: There are still a few minor problems here (see my answer). If you open your console, you'll notice that `couldn't move img` is displayed even though the image was moved successfully (or an error will show up because your quotes are not well escaped).

Comment: please check permission of this folder "../assets/img/horses/", need to writable permission something like 777

Comment: I don't think setting permissions to 777 is a save solution - I gave www-data the ownership of the file instead

Answer (score 0):

This section is problematic

```
$writeimage = fopen($imgPath, "w");
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $imgPath)){
    echo("<script>console.log('couldn't move img');</script>");
} else{
    echo("<script>console.log('image uploaded');</script>");
}
fclose($writeimage);
```

Don't call `fopen` at a path where you expect to perform other file operations.  Also, you have your logic upside down in the `if` check. If the move is successful, you log "*couldn't move img*".  Use this instead:

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $image)){
    echo '<script>console.log("couldn\'t move img");</script>';
} else{
    echo '<script>console.log("image uploaded");</script>';
}
```

Note you also had a couple of other issues that I've fixed here.

1. You didn't escape quotes properly in `echo`,
2. You used parentheses with `echo` (you shouldn't)
3. You switched `$image` to `$imgPath`

Comment: what's wrong with my quotes? The echos always work fine

Comment: @Juliette Take a look at this string, from your original code: `'couldn't move img'`  Where does it end? There is no way for a parsing algorithm to know that the quote after `couldn` should not end the string.  Generally, you can't use the quote that at the beginning and end of a string inside the string, unless you escape it.  That's why I have `couldn\'t`